# Printing only consecutive numbers from an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array in my matlab code, and what I want to do is, 
lets say the array is:

```
wf_array = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11  25 26 28 29 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57]
```

the expected output is : `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 and 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57`

Thus the o/p should contain consecutive numbers from that array if the series is consecutive for at-least 10 numbers.

I have tried the following

```
v = wf_array;
x = [0 cumsum(diff(v)~=1)];
final = v(x==mode(x));
```

but it prints only the longest consecutive stream from that `array` where as it should print all the consecutive streams which are there for at least 10 numbers. Please help...

Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your `cumsum` will count up when there is at least one value that's not consecutive. This means, each of your streams will have a different number in `x`. `mode`, on the other hand, finds only the most frequent number, and the smallest one of them (so if there are several streams of same length, the first one will be taken). According to the documentation for `mode`, "the `mode` function is not suitable for finding peaks in distributions having multiple modes."

So there's 3 ways to tackle this problem. The first is to alter x in a way that makes all streams have the same number. The second is to replace `mode` with something that can find multiple modes. The third is to take a totally different approach and split the array.

I'll take the third one because I think it's the "easiest".

```
w = find( diff(v)~=1 ); %// this contains all indices where the data jumps
x = diff([0 w length(v)]); %// this contains the lengths of the streams
y = mat2cell(v,1,x); %// creates a cell array with each consecutive stream
z = y( cellfun('size',y,2)>=10 ) %// picks those cells with length of at least 10
final = cell2mat(z); %// revert it back to an array
```

Note that this attemp is not robust and will only work on arrays of size `1xN`. If your original input array is differently shaped, you should reshape it first:

```
v = input_array_of_arbitrary_size(:)'; %'// reshapes into row vector columnwise
```

For example, if you input is

```
in = [1 4 7
      2 5 8
      3 6 9];
```

the result will be:

```
v = in(:)' %'//random comment to fix SO's syntax highlighting
v =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

This works for arrays of any dimension and will append each dimension at the end. For details, check out linear indexing.

Comment: thanks for the reply....I want to form an another array from wf_array ....which will have contents like new_wf = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57]...

Comment: After all, I decide on a general attempt. Leave out the last line and you have a cell array. replace the last line with a call to `cell2struct` and you can create a structure array. This last line will create the array from your comment.

Comment: Just to be safe; when I say last line, I mean the line `final = ...`. The following part about robustness is not directly connected to the solution, it's just for people who come here and want to adapt the solution to their own problem.

Comment: thanks @scenia ...i really appreciate the way you solved my problem Thanks a lot :)