# Split consecutive numbers from a row and store in corresponding dynamic variables

Tags: matlab

I have a row vector like this: `x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 15 16 17];`

I want to get two row vectors out of `x` which should have consecutive numbers separately like this:

```
x1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

and

```
x2 = [15 16 17]
```

Comment: this is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547239/printing-only-consecutive-numbers-from-an-array-in-matlab

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the indices where the difference between adjacent elements are `>1` (using `find` and `diff`)
2. Create a vector with the difference between the indices (Use the first element from the index vector, and add the difference between the other elements)
3. Use that vector when splitting the vector using [`mat2cell`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)

Like this:

```
idx = find([diff(x)>1, 1])
did = [idx(1), diff(idx)]
mat2cell(x,1,did)
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a solution (using a slightly more complex example):

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 15 16 17 20:25 33 36:40];
ed = [find(diff(x)>1), numel(x)];  %// edges between groups
res = mat2cell(x, 1, ed-[0 ed(1:end-1)])
```

And the resulting cell array:

```
>> res{1}
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7
>> res{2}
 15    16    17
>> res{3}
 20    21    22    23    24    25
>> res{4}
 33
>> res{5}
 36    37    38    39    40
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a good way! But here's another way for separate arrays:

```
k=[find(diff(x)~=1) length(x)];
t1=1;
for n = 1:length(k)
    t2 = k(n);
    assignin('base', ['x' num2str(n)], x(t1:t2));
    t1 = t2 + 1;
end
```

**Output for your example:-**

```
>> x1
x1 =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7

>> x2
x2 =
    15    16    17
```

Comment: I want matlab to do it automatically. Matlab should: 
1) Recognize that there are two series of consecutive numbers
2) It should make two variables and store them seperately

Comment: @MuhammadAkmal fixed it!